# What is this mains blade connector called?

Tags: components, mains, ul

I've asked around and can't find answers anywhere. I'm designing a PCB that connects to US-style mains blade connectors (that plug into the wall). I've found [these here](https://www.heyco.com/Power_Components/product.cfm?product=PCB-Contacts&section=Power_Components), but I need right angle connectors as the board is at a right angle to the wall. I'm also open to using a connector style like this...

[image]

But I can't find anything like them either. Before I get responses regarding UL and safety, this product requires to be plugged into the wall directly, and I will pursuing UL.

Comment: Have you considered using wires to connect the PCB to the blades?  The stress of connecting and disconnecting will be transferred to the board if they're soldered in and could cause the solder joint or PCB itself to fail.

Comment: Actually, if that PCB connector slides onto blades on the inside of the housing, it would allow considerable flex.

Comment: You'd have to supply a standard cord, but you have this option:   https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/adam-tech/IEC-A-4/9832319?utm_adgroup=Power%20Entry%20Connectors%20-%20Inlets%2C%20Outlets%2C%20Modules&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=Shopping_Product_Connectors%2C%20Interconnects&utm_term=&utm_content=Power%20Entry%20Connectors%20-%20Inlets%2C%20Outlets%2C%20Modules&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI6IiUwqHj8QIVORmtBh36Qge5EAQYASABEgKXd_D_BwE

Comment: Note that your UL listing will be made fantastically more difficult, time consuming and expensive if you use anything that's not already pre-approved by UL (such as the connector I reference above).   Basically you'll have to prove that your design meets all the flammability, creepage, stress, etc.. tests UL has.  And believe me, it's ALOT.   They'll be looking at mechanical stuff too, i.e. you'll need your mechanical and probably material engineers to get involved.   Not trivial.

Comment: And you don't pursue UL listing as a bolt-on or afterthought.  You need to be designing for compliance from the start, and having it guide your decisions.  If you try to backpedal it at the very end, you will wind up failing or having to start over.

Answer (score 7):

That is a [NEMA 1-15P](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NEMA_connector).  The connections internal to that device are probably custom -- connectors are something that are easy enough to make that for volume manufacture you'll often see partial or full custom connectors.

Answer (score 6):

Usually connectors like that are custom sheet metal (a, that are stamped and bent. You could find a sheet metal shop and ask them how they are made. (you could probably unsolder them  and give them to a mechanical consulting firm and they could replicate them or give you a cost)